# Header line doesn't span width of page

Tags: header-footer, margins, fancyhdr

I am using the following code to create a header using `fancyhdr`:

```
\documentclass{report}
    \usepackage[margin=3.0cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}

    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}

    \fancyhf{} % clear the headers
    \fancyhead[R]{%
       % We want italics
       \itshape
       % The chapter number only if it's greater than 0
       \ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \chaptername\ \thechapter. \fi
       % The chapter title
       \leftmark}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

    \fancypagestyle{plain}{
      \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
      \fancyhf{}
      \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
    }

    \setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

The problem is the following:
[image]
The header line doesn't span the whole width of the page.
I suspect this is because I have `\usepackage[margin=3.0cm]{geometry}` loaded which adjusts the margins. How can I make sure that the header line still spans the whole page while keeping these margins?

Comment: Do you want the rule for the whole physical page? The rule is for the text width. Use `\noindent test\hfill test` to see.

Comment: @sigur No it doesn't have to span the whole page, but it should span the text width like you mentioned. Currently it does not. The text runs from the left side of the current line to the same distance but than symmetrically from the rightside.

Comment: @rbm, since you missed the class on your code, I edited, but please, edit and use your class. We don't know what you are loading. Also, you are defining more than one page style.

Comment: @Sigur I forgot indeed but I am using the report class, so your edit is correct.

Comment: Everything works fine here. I can not reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Sigur (+1) for first comment. rbm i think you should explain more

Comment: @Sigur I just tried and you are right. I think some other package is causing the problem. I will update my MWE asap.

Comment: @Sigur I have a very extenisve set of packages in my preamble, which might not make sense to copy here. I tried to uncomment each of them one by one but to no avail. My hope is that someone can think of statements that can cause this based on the image.

Comment: @HarishKumar Thanks, but that unfortunately doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Paste it here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and send us the link.

Comment: @Sigur Here it is: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10960153/ I have to warn you that it is a bit of a mess though.

Comment: Ok just load geometry befor fancyhdr

Comment: @touhami Thanks! That works :)! If you make it into answer I will accept it. I was under the impression that package order shouldn't matter as latex would adjust after compiling twice (just as with hyperlinks).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

loading `geometry` befor `fancyhdr` will fix it

```
\usepackage[margin=3.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```